# Add CSS to HTML checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have encountered some problem with my site. I want to add CSS to my button to be something like this which I found on the web. https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/WjZVjo
I can't add an ID to it as I can't change the HTML code as it is auto generated by Wordpress. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<label class='grunion-field-label checkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='g84-iagreetothetermsconditions' value='Yes' class='checkbox' required aria-required='true' />
    I agree to the Terms &amp; Conditions. <span>(required)</span>
</label>
```

Comment: You could use [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: *I can't change the HTML code as it is auto generated by Wordpress* - why can't you?

Comment: How is it generated by Wordpress? Are you using a Plugin for that? If yes, which?

Comment: Can you try editing the css file and add `label.checkbox .grunion-field-label{yourCss}` ? (same idea for the rest of the classes)

Comment: You can't use that anyway as your input is inside your label - you need the input to be before the label if you want to use the styles in the codepen

Comment: can you send more code of html i want the parent of label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add external css to re-style the checkbox and also you may need to get some help from  javascript.

```js
(function($) {

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('label').addClass('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('label').removeClass('checked');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.grunion-field-label.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
.grunion-field-label.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.grunion-field-label.checkbox:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.grunion-field-label.checkbox.checked:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.grunion-field-label.checkbox.checked:before {
  background-color: #0c0;
  border-color: #0c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='grunion-field-label checkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='g84-iagreetothetermsconditions' value='Yes' class='checkbox' required aria-required='true' />
    I agree to the Terms &amp; Conditions. <span>(required)</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, I got this too high. Anyway to solve? https://i.imgur.com/d3gsjb6.jpg

Comment: Try to adjust the value of `top` in both `before` and `after` pseudo elements.

Comment: Works great! Thanks, do you know how to edit the font weight of "I agree to the Terms &amp; Conditions."

Answer (score 1):

With your current DOM structure you go with following snippet:

```css
.grunion-field-label {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:10px;
  line-height:30px;
}

.grunion-field-label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
  content:"";
}

.grunion-field-label input[type="checkbox"] + span::after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.grunion-field-label input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.grunion-field-label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span::after {
  border-color: #f00;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class='grunion-field-label checkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='g84-iagreetothetermsconditions' value='Yes' class='checkbox' required aria-required='true' />
    I agree to the Terms &amp; Conditions. <span>(required)</span>
</label>
```